# Formula that depending the date of payment will assign the value of that payment

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

Another question from a newbie( most probably a silly one). I have dates of payments(date) with payments(currency). I created an amount paid field where `CASE( Payment_Date__c ,  Relation__r.X1__c ,  Relation__r.Deposit__c ,NULL)`. This works. But when I try to implement 15 different dates with 15 different payments( each payment is linked to a date) -->

```
 CASE( "Payment_Date__c" ,  
 Relation__r.X1__c ,  
 Relation__r.Deposit__c ,  
 Relation__r.X2_Date__c ,
 Relation__r.X2_Payment__c,
 Relation__r.X3_Date__c, 
 Relation__r.X3_Payment__c,
 Relation__r.X4_Date__c ,
 Relation__r.X4_Payment__c, 
 Relation__r.X5_Date__c ,  
 Relation__r.X5_Deposit__c,
 NULL)
```

I get an error like Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'CASE()'. Expected Text, received Date.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Why is `Payment_Date__c` in double quotes in your example that is not working?

Comment: Was digging onto formulas book and found out that was my bad syntax. Figured it out : CASE( Payment_Date__c , 
Relation__r.X1__c , Relation__r.Deposit__c ,Relation__r.X2_Date__c , Relation__r.X2_Payment__c, Relation__r.X3_Date__c , Relation__r.X3_Payment__c ,  NULL)

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE( Payment_Date__c , Relation__r.X1__c , Relation__r.Deposit__c ,Relation__r.X2_Date__c , Relation__r.X2_Payment__c, Relation__r.X3_Date__c , Relation__r.X3_Payment__c , NULL)
```

Ok the answer is the one above!!!